# Como interromper o algoritmo?

Tags: python

Não estou conseguindo interromper a execução do programa, caso o aluno seja aprovado sem recuperação. Já tentei return e break, mas, não funcionou.

```
n1 = int(input('Insira a nota da prova 1: '))
n2 = int(input('Insira a nota da prova 2: '))

media = (n1 + n2) / 2


print ('A média é: ', media)

if media > 5:
    print ('Aprovado')
else:
    print ('Reprovado')
         
if media < 5:
    recuperação = int(input('Nota da recuperação: '))
    media_rec = (media + recuperação)/2
    print ('A média é: ', media_rec)
if media_rec > 5:
    print ('Aprovado')
else:
    print ('Reprovado')`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não consegui compreender a sua dúvida, pois, rodei seu código aqui e deu tudo certo! Se o problema for que quando o aluno é aprovado, o outro bloco if também passa no teste retornando "aprovado" duas vezes é bem simples de resolver, é só mover o bloco da nota de recuperação dentro do teu primeiro bloco else ficando dessa forma:

```
`n1 = int(input('Insira a nota da prova 1: '))
n2 = int(input('Insira a nota da prova 2: '))

media = (n1 + n2) / 2

media_rec = media

print ('A média é: ', media)

if media > 5:
    print ('Aprovado')
else:
    if media < 5:
        recuperação = int(input('Nota da recuperação: '))
        media_rec = (media + recuperação)/2
        print ('A média é: ', media_rec)
    if media_rec > 5:
        print ('Aprovado')
    else:
        print ('Reprovado')`
```

Como pode ver apenas idententei o 2° bloco if/else dentro do 1° else e removi uma das duas intruções "print('reprovado')

Quanto a razão de nem o `return`, nem o `break` e nem o `return break` funcionarem é que eles são "métodos" (por assim dizer) especificos de outras estruturas lógicas e funções. O "return" só funciona e é válido em uma função no teu caso se você tivesse pegado esse código e transformado ele numa função e pedisse para que a função retornasse um print do estado do aluno. Já o "break" é exclusivo do laço de repetição "while", que no teu caso serveria para aprovar/reprovar n alunos, ou seja, enquanto tiver n alunos repita as perguntas atribuições e etc. Quando não tiver mais n alunos (que pode ser um input do usuário) break que pararia a repetição.

Comment: Complementando: o `break` pode ser usado dentro de um `for` também.

Comment: Correto! Esqueci de faler esse caso, mas obrigado pelo complemento

Answer (score 3):

Caro,

A identação no Python é crucial.

Seu último `if` que testa `media_rec` será executado independente de o aluno ter passado ou não e esta variável só é inicializada se o aluno ficar em recuperação.

Duas soluções

### 1 - Fazer o media_rec ser igual a media. Esta é uma solução feia e vai ter um bug, pois se `Aprovado` a mensagem aparecerá duas vezes

```
n1 = int(input('Insira a nota da prova 1: '))
n2 = int(input('Insira a nota da prova 2: '))

media = (n1 + n2) / 2

media_rec = media

print ('A média é: ', media)

if media > 5:
    print ('Aprovado')
else:
    print ('Reprovado')
         
if media < 5:
    recuperação = int(input('Nota da recuperação: '))
    media_rec = (media + recuperação)/2
    print ('A média é: ', media_rec)
if media_rec > 5:
    print ('Aprovado')
else:
    print ('Reprovado')
```

### 2 - Identar de forma correta e melhorar os `if`

```
n1 = int(input('Insira a nota da prova 1: '))
n2 = int(input('Insira a nota da prova 2: '))

media = (n1 + n2) / 2


print ('A média é: ', media)

if media >= 5:
    print ('Aprovado')
elif media < 5:
    print ('Reprovado')
    recuperação = int(input('Nota da recuperação: '))
    media_rec = (media + recuperação)/2
    print ('A média é: ', media_rec)
    if media_rec > 5:
        print ('Aprovado')
    else:
        print ('Reprovado')
```

Epero que ajude.